# Environment variables not picked up in build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
ENV VUE_APP_BACKEND_SERVER=${_VUE_APP_BACKEND_SERVER}
RUN echo "server env is:"
RUN echo $VUE_APP_BACKEND_SERVER
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run gcpbuild
```

#### Cloudbuild config

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - '--no-cache'
      - '-t'
      - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - front
      - '-f'
      - front/Dockerfile
      - '--build-arg=ENV=$_VUE_APP_BACKEND_SERVER'
    id: Build
...
...
options:
  substitutionOption: ALLOW_LOOSE
substitutions:
  _VUE_APP_BACKEND_SERVER: 'https://backend.url'
```

I have also set the variable in the substitutions in the 'Advanced' section. However during the build the `echo` prints a blank and the variable is not available in the app as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
ARG VUE_APP_BACKEND_SERVER
...
```

Also, fix build-arg line in your cloud build config:

```
- '--build-arg',
- 'VUE_APP_BACKEND_SERVER=${_VUE_APP_BACKEND_SERVER}'
```

Check out the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#yaml_2).

[Read more](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) about ARG directive in Dockerfiles.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I had read that page of the docs about 20 times but found it very hard to follow.